# Attach random file to a pdf using itText

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to attach files to a pdf document using iText. Files can be images, xml, txt, pdf, etc.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method with `src` the path to the original document, `dest` the path to the newly created PDF, and `attachments` is an array of paths to the files you want to attach:

```
public void addAttachments(
  String src, String dest, String[] attachments) throws IOException, DocumentException {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
  for (int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    addAttachment(stamper.getWriter(), new File(attachments[i]));
  }
  stamper.close();
}

protected void addAttachment(PdfWriter writer, File src) throws IOException {
  PdfFileSpecification fs =
    PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, src.getAbsolutePath(), src.getName(), null);
  writer.addFileAttachment(src.getName().substring(0, src.getName().indexOf('.')), fs);
}
```

Comment: iText doesn't support conversion of PDF->PDF/A "out of the box".

Comment: instead of converting pdf/a from pdf ,can I generate a pdf/a document pdfwriter.setproperties...etc..

Answer (score 0):

Short Question, short answer :D

[itext API : addFileAttachment](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#addFileAttachment%28java.lang.String,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification%29)